# cmd(git): FileNotFoundError when executing git commands on heroku through Python

Tags: python-3.x, git, github, heroku, discord.py

I have been developing a **Discord Bot (Discord.py)** for some time now and wish to backup some of the databases which store information about the members of the server, I have been hosting my Bot on **Heroku** through GitHub. The Database I wish to backup lives on another repository, different form the one where my code lives.I thought backing it up on GitHub would be a good idea, so I wrote a script that executed git commands, committed and pushed my code to origin. I also renamed my *.git* folder while committing so it can store that in the back up too.

Now, for the problem, whenever the script tries to execute a git command it throws an exception as follows

***cmd(git): FileNotFoundError #The_command# was not found as a file or directory***

The code works perfectly fine on my computer, it just decides to stop working on the server I host it on, I have tried changing to Repl.it form GitHub and Heroku, but **the same exact error** persists.I think it cannot find the path of git while on a remote server, but can on a local machine.

My **commit()**  method is been provided below

So can anyone help me with this or tell me a better way of doing what I am trying to do?  Any an all help will be greatly appreciated.

````
    from git import Repo
    import git
    from datetime import datetime

    def commit(sp_msg: str()):

        os.rename("./Database/gothy", "./Database/.git")

        now = datetime.now()
        date_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        commit_msg = f"Database updated - {date_time} -> {sp_msg} "
        g = git.Git("./Database")
        try:
            g.execute(f'git commit -a -m "{commit_msg}" ')
            g.execute("git push")

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        os.rename("./Database/.git", "./Database/gothy")```
````

Comment: Maybe the `git` command is simply not installed on the server on which your code is running?

Comment: How do install git in heroku? I have Gitpython in my dependencies but I don't think adding git in my dependencies will work since its not a python library